# Multiple Connections + JPA + Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have 2 DataSource connections and I am specifying which class each connection should use but I still get some exception:

this is my applicationContext.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.video"/> 
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven />  
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="VOD" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/VOD" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="SB" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/SB" />



     <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="VOD" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.video" />
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean> 


     <bean id="entityManagerFactorySB"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="SB" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.service" />
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerSB" 
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorySB"/>
    </bean> 

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.video"
                        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" 
                        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.service"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactorySB" 
transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerSB"/>
```

and here is my persistence.xml

```
  <persistence-unit name="VOD" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <class>com.example.video.model.Product</class>
                             .
                             .
       <class>com.example.video.model.Task</class>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> 

       <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
       </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
   <persistence-unit name="SB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <class>com.example.service.model.ChargingInfo</class>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the exception: 
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: CHARGINGINFO

Comment: Do you have CHARGINGINFO table in your database?

Comment: yes I do, The DB is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, just had to remove the line from applicationContext.xml

<
prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate

from the bean declarations then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have You checked MergingPersistenceUnitManager  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.misc.merging-persistence-units
Allows you to have multiple persistence providers combined to one.